# VB.NET | Crystal Report always showing Login

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports

I've seen a lot of question related to mine, but I still can't find a hint with my problem.

here is my code

```
Dim cryRpt1 As New ReportDocument
cryRpt1.Load(reportsfolder + "ApplicationFormBack.rpt")

Dim crTable1 As CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.Table
Dim crTableLogonInfo1 As CrystalDecisions.Shared.TableLogOnInfo
Dim ConnInfo1 As New CrystalDecisions.Shared.ConnectionInfo()

ConnInfo1.ServerName = tmpSN
ConnInfo1.DatabaseName = tmpDBN
ConnInfo1.UserID = tmpUID
ConnInfo1.Password = tmpPass

For Each crTable1 In cryRpt1.Database.Tables
    crTableLogonInfo1 = crTable1.LogOnInfo
    crTableLogonInfo1.ConnectionInfo = ConnInfo1
    crTable1.ApplyLogOnInfo(crTableLogonInfo1)
Next

cryRpt1.SetDataSource(cmdtbCO)

cryRpt1.Subreports(0).SetDataSource(cmdtableAM)
cryRpt1.Subreports(1).SetDataSource(cmdtableCO)
cryRpt1.Subreports(2).SetDataSource(cmdtableBO)
cryRpt1.Subreports(3).SetDataSource(cmdtableREM)
cryRpt1.Subreports(4).SetDataSource(cmdtableSignatory)

AppFormViewer.CrystalReportViewer2.ReportSource = cryRpt1
AppFormViewer.CrystalReportViewer2.LogOnInfo(0).ConnectionInfo.IntegratedSecurity = False
AppFormViewer.CrystalReportViewer2.Refresh()
AppFormViewer.CrystalReportViewer2.ShowPrintButton = True
.ShowDialog()
```

what could be the problem of this code. Am I missing something?

this is what my report looks like

[image]

Comment: Are these (cmdTableAM, cmdTableCO, etc) all DataTable types? Do you use XSD as data source inside Crystal Reports design interface?

Comment: yes those are DataTables

Comment: Have you tried not setting any of the DatabaseLogon properties of Crystal Reports and instead just use .SetDataSource(<your data table>)?

Comment: like removing this `For Each crTable1 In cryRpt1.Database.Tables
                crTableLogonInfo1 = crTable1.LogOnInfo
                crTableLogonInfo1.ConnectionInfo = ConnInfo1
                crTable1.ApplyLogOnInfo(crTableLogonInfo1)
            Next 
part?

Comment: The way I do it is: `Dim crpt As New SalesReport Dim sales As DataTable = GetSalesReport() crpt.SetDataSource(sales)`. If I have subreports, `Dim subReport As New CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument subReport = 
 crpt.OpenSubReport("subreport") Dim table2 = GetSales2() subReport.SetDataSource(table2)`. Also, I use XSD as my data source in Crystal Report design.